# WPF different Window Icon & Taskbar Icon

Tags: .net, wpf, taskbar

Is it possible in WPF to have a different Icon for the Window and the Taskbar.
In my special scenario I want to have a an Icon with transparency for the Window and one "Metro" Style (with colored Background) for the Taskbar.

Setting the Application-Icon different didn't work, Taskbar always shows the Window Icon.

Anybody can offer a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Window icon always is 16px, and the Icon in the taskbar is larger (I don't know which size is used, but I would guess 32x32), you can make an icon which has different content for different sizes.

A standard icon is usually 64x64 or 48x48, and scaled down for the rest of the sizes. If you instead create one 48x48 icon, with a colored background, and one 16x16 icon with no background, your app will use the 16x icon for the window icon, and the 48x icon for the taskbar.