# Different icon for Window and Taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

Is it possible to use different icons for Window and taskbar button? 
I have a window with custom height, so the window icon is bigger than usual and I cannot apply [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319206/wpf-different-window-icon-taskbar-icon). If the window icon is set, it's being used for the taskbar as well, despite having the .ico set for the exe.

Is it possible to force the app to use the .ico for the taskbar instead of the window icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, no. What you can do is create your own custom title bar, drawing your icon, adding your own title label, and any custom close/minimize/maximize buttons as required.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, but I had hopes that a hacky way to set it would save me from doing all that stuff :D. Thanks for your reply!